# Retrieving all tags with multiple conditions without knowing the names of the respective attributes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find all tags that have attribute values equal to "ATTR1" and "ATTR2" without knowing the corresponding attribute names.

Let's assume I have the following:

```
page_content = '''<a href="ATTR1">text1</a>
<div class="random_value" type="ATTR2">text2</div>
<script class="ATTR1" id="ATTR2">text3</script>
<span class="random_value" id="ATTR2">text5</span>'''
```

I would like to have a script that retrieves only the third element, which has an attribute equal to "ATTR1" AND an attribute equal to "ATTR2". That is, I need the following:

```
<script class="ATTR1" id="ATTR2">text3</script>
```

I know I can pass a function as an argument to `find_all()`. But, I need help understanding how I can write a function that returns true if these conditions are met.

Comment: Providing the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue, would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing the attribute names, simply chain your conditions e.g. with [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
select('#ATTR2.ATTR1')
```

Or **without knowing the attributes** and just checking all values against:

```
for e in soup():
    attr_list = [v for i in list(e.attrs.values()) for v in (i if isinstance(i,list) else [i])]
    if all(x in attr_list for x in ['ATTR1','ATTR2']):
        print(e)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<a href="ATTR1">text1</a>
<div class="random_value" type="ATTR2">text2</div>
<script class="ATTR1" id="ATTR2">text3</script>
<span class="random_value" id="ATTR2">text5</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.select('#ATTR2.ATTR1'))

for e in soup():
    attr_list = [v for i in list(e.attrs.values()) for v in (i if isinstance(i,list) else [i])]
    if all(x in attr_list for x in ['ATTR1','ATTR2']):
        print(e)
```

##### Output

```
[<script class="ATTR1" id="ATTR2">text3</script>]

[<script class="ATTR1" id="ATTR2">text3</script>]
```